# PHP: Gmail rechaza las peticiones de PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail

Estoy intentando enviar correos con PHPMailer -la típica funcionalidad web para restaurar contraseñas de usuarios- desde mi local haciendo uso de una cuenta de Gmail, pero creo que por motivos de seguridad Gmail rechaza la petición:

```
2022-07-26 16:22:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x3-20020adff0c3000000b0021deba99142sm14582275wro.40 - gsmtp
2022-07-26 16:22:53 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x3-20020adff0c3000000b0021deba99142sm14582275wro.40 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2022-07-26 16:22:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2022-07-26 16:22:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection x3-20020adff0c3000000b0021deba99142sm14582275wro.40 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Antes había una opción para "Permitir el acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras", pero la han eliminado y ahora en su lugar hay que autorizar el acceso de terceros de manera individualizada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Sabéis si es posible incluir mi local en la lista segura de mi cuenta de Gmail? ¿O es mejor que me abra una cuenta de correo en un servidor más permisivo para intentar el envío?

Comment: Aun se puede, esta pregunta de SO en ingles puede ayudarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533461/php-mailer-could-not-authenticate-error-all-of-a-sudden-with-gmail

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=es

Comment: Genial, la solución de SO internacional funciona perfectamente.